# Mapping groups of events to segments using a logarithmic scale

Tags: javascript, math, logarithm

I have some events (an array of groups of events) and I want to map those events to segments using a logarithmic scale.

There are some rules I want the solution to obey to:

1. Math.log(x+1) must be used as it scales well 1 and numbers smaller than 1
2. I want to calculate the single segments and not only the total
3. The sum of the segments of a group i must be equal to the sum of the segments of another 
     group j if the linear sums of the events are equal (i.e. if I have the events [1, 1] and [2] the total
     of the mapped segments of the two groups must be equal)

I have developed the solution you see below but it works partially, as the sum of groups[0].segments is different from the sum of groups[1].segments, because log(1+1)+log(1+1) != log(2+1)

How can I use Math.log(x+1) to scale the events while having rule 3 working?

```js
var logSegmentLen = function(x) {
  return Math.log(x+1);
}

var groupOfSegmentsTotal = function(segmentLenFn) {
  var f = function(arrayOfSegments) {
    let segments = arrayOfSegments.map(segmentLenFn);
    let total = segments.reduce((a,b) => a+b,0);
    return {
      total: total,
      segments: segments      
    }
  }
  return f;
}

var events = [ [1, 1], [2]]
var groups = events.map(groupOfSegmentsTotal(logSegmentLen));
console.log(groups[0].segments, groups[1].segments);
console.log(Math.abs(groups[0].total - groups[1].total) < 0.001); // true must be printed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I use Math.log(x+1) to scale the events while having rule 3 working?

Apparently this is just impossible. Your requirement #3 which can be restated as for given scale function `F(x)`

```
sum(Xi) = sum(Yj)  =>  sum(F(Xi)) = sum(F(Yj))
```

actually implies that the only `F(x)` that fits it is of form `F(x) = k*x` i.e. just a linear scale. Any non-linear scale (including logarithmic) will break that requirement. You probably should describe your higher-level problem and somebody might be able to come up with non-self-contradicting translation of that problem.

***Sidenote*** Sketch of the proof. Fix {Xi} to be just a collection of `n` identical values `x` and {Yj} to be a collection of `m` identical `y`. So

```
sum(Xi) = n*x
sum(Yj) = m*y
sum(F(Xi)) = n*F(x)
sum(F(Yj)) = m*F(y)
```

and the requirement becomes:

```
sum(Xi) = sum(Yj)  =>  sum(F(Xi)) = sum(F(Yj))
n*x = m*y => n*F(x) = m*F(y)
```

And this holds for arbitrary integers `n` and `m`. Now lets fix `F(1)` = `k`. It means that for any `m/n` `F(m/n) = m/n*k`. As real numbers can be approximated by fractions with arbitrary precision, it means that for any `x` `F(x) = x*k`.

Comment: I have to draw events as an histogram, I have events like [1, 1], [2], which must generate two segments, the first composed of two subsegments, the second of one segment. The two segments have to have equal length. This is what I meant.

Comment: I believe I solved the problem, I calculated at first log(total+1)/log(max+1) where total is the total on the segment and max is max(total_i) which gives the length of the segment. Then, to draw the inner part of the segment, i.e. the subsegments, I applied the solution you gave here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47336655/calculating-the-subsegments-of-a-line-using-logarithmic-scaling

Comment: @cdarwin, sorry I don't think I understand from your comments what is the problem you are trying to solve and how logarithmic scale is related to it.

Comment: no problem, the segments are now drawn :-). Logarithmic scaling is used to represent values which can differ by an order of magnitude